# Apache Storm command line client in python

Tags: python-3.x, apache-storm

I am new to python and using storm (1.0.1) on hdinsight . When i searched , all i can see is developing storm using python. But i need the help on below.
can you please let me know how can i use storm "command line client" like 
1) storm list 2) storm monitor 3) storm kill using python
As of now, i do ssh to connect hdinsight and execute these commands. how can i do the same in python and what are the library functions do i need to import?
is there any blog/documentation. 
Appreciate your help!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you need to call these commands through Python, but it is possible. You can call the same commands as the Storm CLI through Thrift. A good starting point would be looking at the commands Streamparse has implemented here https://github.com/Parsely/streamparse/tree/master/streamparse/cli.

The Storm CLI is also based on Python (which calls into Java classes, which do the Thrift calls mentioned above). Take a look at https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/bin/storm.py.